# htaccess identical folder and file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I set up an htaccess that can distinguish a file from a folder with the same name?

I have under my website

```
index.php
team.php
team/Justin.php
team/martin.php...
```

and a htaccess with a URL Rewrite to make nice url and remove the .php

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately when I go to the url mywebsite.com/team it goes straight to the team folder...
I would like

> mywebsite.com/team goes to --> team.php page
>
> mywebsite.com/team/xxx goes to --> any pages in the folder
>   team.

Thanks,

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because **/team** maps to an existent directory. When you request **/team** server changes the uri to **/team/** adding a directory slash thus it goes to the dir.

You have to turn off the DirectorySlash.

Add the following line to your .htaccess

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This will allow you to access **/team.php** as **/team** without trailing slash.

You can use this htaccess :

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks, now it is not adding the directory slash anymore but for some reason the team page is not showing up Page not found.

Comment: that's what I put on my htaccess but I cannot access the team.php page using the /team url, it says Page not found.
"The requested URL /mywebsite.com/team was not found on this server."

Comment: @starkeen I have attempted to use this solution, but it does not seem to work. have you tested it?