# Subdirectory is being accessed instead of a html file of the same name

Tags: html, .htaccess, server, subdirectory

So, I've just got my .htaccess file working and it removes the `.html` extensions just fine. However, I now have a problem where a url pointing to my work page `www.mywebsite.com/work` is now targeting the subdirectory `work` which contains all the specific project files that can be accessed via the work.html page. I made the subdirectory because I want the url string to read as `www.mywebsite.com/work/project-name` whilst also having a clean and organised root folder instead of filling it up with 100+ html files.

I've searched for a solution all day but I feel like my limited knowledge is causing me to overlook the answer, so I apologise if this is a dupe. I thought I'd ask specifically on here as a last resort. Would love any suggestions from you, and if this already has a clear answer, please mark this as a dupe and point me in the right direction!

Incase it might help, the contents of my .htaccess file are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193414/htaccess-identical-folder-and-file-name/38194121

Comment: @Amit I came across this one but like many others in that post, the solution proposed doesn't work. It removes the slash, sure, but it doesn't locate the html file it's meant to be accessing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a good solution to this that also follows the fix admitted by Amit.

Firstly, add `DirectorySlash Off`

then I removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

and finally I removed the "!" from "!-f". Overall, the .htaccess should look like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Solution was found in [this post](http://DirectorySlash%20Off%20%20RewriteEngine%20On%20RewriteCond%20%25%7BREQUEST_FILENAME%7D%5C.html%20-f%20RewriteRule%20%5E(%5B%5E%5C.%5D+)$%20$1.html%20%5BNC,L%5D).